# CoffeeScript: How to iterate through many levels of recursive data?

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript

I have many levels of nested comments inside my **commentsArray**

(This is pulled in from an API and cannot be changed)

```
commentsArray = [
    {
        author: "jeff"
        replies: [
            {
                author: "jeff"
                replies: [
                    {
                        author: "simon"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                author: "simon"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        author: "simon"
    }
]
```

I also have a recursive function, **dialogueParse**, that calls itself if the object in question has "**replies**"

```
dialogueParse = (comment) ->
    for child in comment
        if child.author is "simon"
            console.log "Simon was found.."

        if child.replies
            dialogueParse child
```

However, this code doesn't seem to work correctly. After I call the function initially:

```
dialogueParse commentsArray
```

..for some reason, only the one located on the first level (at the end of the array) is found.

"**simon**" is listed as an author in 3 different places.

I've been working on this for several hours and getting nowhere. Any help is more than appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be passing `child.replies` as the argument in the recursion?

As in:

```
dialogueParse = (comment) ->
    for child in comment
        if child.author is "simon"
            console.log "Simon was found.."

        if child.replies
            dialogueParse child.replies
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple mistake..apparently I need some sleep. Thank you so much!